# Ubuntu doesn't recognise Internal Hard Drive

Tags: boot, hard-drive

All of a sudden yesterday when I boot Ubuntu 20.04 from EFI (grub) it just goes to a black screen. In the BIOs it recognises my Hard Drive as the 250Gb Samsung SSD but when I go to load ubuntu, black screen.

So I loaded Ubuntu from a USB and when I went to install there was nothing on the Drives page. I cancelled the installation and went to "Try Ubuntu" and into Disks and the only disks it showed were the loop stuff and the 32Gb USB stick, didn't pick up the 250Gb Internal Hard Drive.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I don't mind a clean reinstall if something is corrupted but I do need files off the original install

[image]

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now resolved so I'll share what I did.

I booted Ubuntu via a flash drive, and when I ran fsdisk -l it didn't pick up the internal SSD.

I went to power off the machine and accidentally clicked Suspend. Pressed the power button to wake the machine up from that state, ran fsdisk -l again and .... the SDD showed.

The SDD must have believed it was in a suspended state.After this all was working fine again

Answer (score -1):

BIOS can have accidentally switched the boot priority or altered the order of hard disks in favor of displaying the flash stick first, thus showing a black screen. I've encountered it once.
Another possibility is to attach any external HDD/SSD/flash stick with Linux on it, boot from it, check with `fdisk -l` and start `fsck` for the malfunctioning drive.

Comment: Hey, fdisk -l from the flash stick only shows /dev/sda1 empty, /dev/sda2 3.9M EFI and /dev/sda3 the 32Gb flash stick. Doesn't pick up the 250Gb internal SDD

Comment: Not even a trace of /dev/sdb and its partition(s)? What's shown by `lshw -C storage` ?