# Ubuntu 20 won't go further than Desktop screen

Tags: boot

So I've been having an issue for a few weeks that if my laptop accidentally goes into a suspended state, Ubuntu won't boot. To resolve it I start ubuntu from a flash usb, suspend it, unsuspend it and then i'm good to boot from EFI after that ([Ubuntu doesn't recognise Internal Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395756/ubuntu-doesnt-recognise-internal-hard-drive/1395761?noredirect=1#comment2416386_1395761))

But today I'm getting a different issue.

I can boot Ubuntu fine, and it loads up and goes to the desktop. But then I can't do anything at all, can't click on anything. Every minute or so the screen flashes and then reloads the desktop.

I pressed ctrl + shift + f1 to try and get to a terminal and it just has lots of rows saying:
systemd-journal[268]: Failed to write entry(22 items), ignoring: Read-only file system

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a dying hard drive to me. Is there anything in your `/var/log/syslog` file that points to bad blocks/sectors?

Comment: First off there is no Ubuntu 20, no such version.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 20 is a server system designed for *headless* operation and not desktop use. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is available in a desktop system, but there is no desktop for Ubuntu 20 systems (they are Server only; 20 & 20.04 are different products)